# Enable "parent":[] in REST export view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8

I have multi level taxonomy with 2 levels, but when I run REST export on it, "parent":[], always stays blank - no matter how many levels there is.

How can I expose relations within taxonomy via restful?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in core, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2543726
In the meantime, you could write a new normalizer service that is only for terms.